# Install a local svn dependence on composer

Tags: svn, composer-php

Currently my projects through version SVN, which also use Composer to control dependencies on them. 
In one of my projects I'm trying to set another project as my dependency, but I can not do it.

In my main project I'm trying to set `composer.json` like this:

```
{
    "name": "my/project",
    "description": "",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "svn",
            "url": "http://myhost.com:81/svn/Dependency/",
            "branches-path": "branches/",
            "tags-path": "tags/",
            "trunk-path": "trunk/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/dependency": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

And the `composer.json` of my dependency:

```
{
    "name": "my/dependency",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Hasteasy\\": "lib/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    }
}
```

In my main project when I run `composer install`, the following occurs:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package my/dependency could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see  for more details.

Read  for further common problems.
```

---

The only way I could do my main project download dependency is defining the repository as a `package`, but this way the composer does not run `composer install` in my dependency.

Any suggestions to solve this problem? I'm leaving to perform some configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I found a parameter in `composer.json` that must be set: `"minimum-stability": "dev"`
After setting it in the main project dependencies have been downloaded successfully.
My files were as follows:

Main project:

```
{
    "name": "my/project",
    "description": "",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "svn",
            "url": "http://myhost.com:81/svn/Dependency/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/dependency": "dev"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev
}
```

Dependency project:

```
{
    "name": "my/dependency",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Hasteasy\\": "lib/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    }
}
```